# distributed tracing not working for Netty Server with opentelemetry

Tags: open-telemetry

I am using netty server for processing tcp message. during this call we are calling rest api of an microservice and want to have tracing information logged from netty server to microservice. I tried configuring opentelemetry but its not working.please help

Answer (score 1):

Netty is a very generic networking library. The [OpenTelemetry instrumentation for Netty](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/netty) is written specifically for the Netty Http Client and Server classes. Instrumentation for other usages is not supported.